# Error while creating endpoints for Azure Digital Twin time series visualization

Tags: azure, azure-digital-twins

I am trying out the Azure Digital Twins solution.  In the Time Series visualization step, I am getting an error while creating the endpoints.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/digital-twins/tutorial-facilities-analyze

Trying to create the endpoint as given in section "Create an endpoint for the event hub" is giving error:

```
Response Status: 400, BadRequest , {"error":{"code":"400.600.000.000","message":"Attempting to provision 'EventHub' endpoint resulted in exception 'Put token failed. status-code: 404, status-description: The messaging entity 'sb://v...
```

Any pointers to fix this?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the request body its tricky to troubleshoot definitively. However, the first go-to troubleshooting tip would be does your endpoint contain the `EntityPath` at the end of the connection string? EntityPath is not typically added by default when copying a connection string from the portal.

*Endpoint=sb://nameOfYourEventHubNamespace.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=ManageSend;SharedAccessKey=yourShareAccessKey1GUID;**EntityPath=nameOfYourEventHub***

Comment: Thanks for looking into this, Tyler. The EntityPath is present for both primary as well as secondary keys. Ex: 
```
Endpoint=sb://vaidya-digital-twins-event-hubs-namespace.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=ManageSend;SharedAccessKey=<key value>;EntityPath=vaidya-digital-twins-event-hub.
```
Unfortunately the response body string is truncated and so I am not able to figure out the exact issue.

Comment: Next you should ensure that the Path is set to the name of the `EventHub` created within your `EventHubNamespace` not the name of the Namespace. The error you are seeing is due to a validation that the EventHub you are passing DigitalTwins actually exists (protection from typos, though still in preview and rather rough).  

Where are you seeing the truncated response body?

Comment: Thanks, Tyler.  Verified that the entity path is indeed set to event-hub ("vaidya-digital-twins-event-hub") and not the namespace (which has the namespace appended to it).  The truncated response body is the console output on executing the "dotnet run CreateEndpoints" command.

Comment: Oh! There is a typo in the config instructions on the page you linked. The `path` variable in the `actions\createEndpoints.yaml` config should read `Name_of_your_Event_Hub` not the namespace. This is the same value as your `EntityPath`.